# How to get the Excel List values in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook in which say i have a cell A1 with dropdown list created using a formula.
this is a dynamic list and keeps changing on other inputs.
For example
A1 will have a dropdown list of Apple, Orange, Pear

I want to read this list in VBA. Can any one help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example - in reality you should test there's validation and it's a List type etc:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim vList
    vList = Evaluate(Range("A1").Validation.Formula1)
End Sub
```

Comment: How do i read this vList, is this an array, i am not able to get vList(0) or count of it

Comment: It's a 2D array and 1-based, so use `vList(1, 1)` for example.